# Is `argv [0]` of `execve()` required to be the same as the basename component of the `pathname` argument?

Tags: bash, exec

In

```
#include <unistd.h>
int execve(const char * pathname , char *const  argv [], char *const  envp []);
```

`argv [0]` of `execve` corresponds to `argv[0]` in the main function of the new program, and is thus typically the same as  the basename component of the `pathname` argument. 
Is it a requirement that we should always follow?

When a program file can be invoked by different values of `argv[0]`, does that rule/convention mean that when I invoke a program file and want `argv[0]` of its `main()` to have a specific value,  I have to create a symlink to the program file named after the value of `argv[0]`, and invoke the program by the symlink? Or not necessarily?
For example, [this answer to “Why does argv include the program name?”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315817/674) says

> Bash runs in POSIX mode when `argv[0]` is `sh`. It runs as a login shell when `argv[0]` begins with `-`.

Does that mean that

- to invoke bash in POSIX mode, I have to create a symlink `/path/to/sh` to `/bin/bash` and invoke bash by `execve("/path/to/sh", argv, ...)` with `argv[0]` pointing to string `"sh"`? Is this way preferrable over `execve("/bin/bash", argv, ...)` where `argv[1]` points to string `"--posix"` and `argv[0]` doesn't matter?
- to invoke bash as a login shell, I have to create a symlink `/path/to/-` to `/bin/bash` and invoke bash by `execve("/path/to/-", argv, ...)` with `argv[0]` pointing to string `"-"`? Is this way preferable over `execve("/bin/bash", argv, ...)` where `argv[1]` points to string `"--login"` and `argv[0]` doesn't matter?

When is it useful that `argv [0]` of `execve`  is **not the same** as the basename component of the `pathname` argument?

Comment: What question are you getting at here? Besides the title, you have eight questions in the Question.  You don't invoke bash from the command-line via `execve()`, so I don't know which way you're going with this question.

Comment: Number of question marks doesn't matter. To entertain you, I can end every sentence with a question mark. If I know my answer clearly, I wouldn't post my confusion. If my confusion confuses you, you don't understand that I am asking questions.

Comment: Just my opinion, but your Question diverges between using a system call execve() and using symlinks to invoke bash.  Maybe I'm not smart enough to understand where you're going.

Comment: It is more about acceptance than smartness.

Comment: Questions should be answerable, because you want Answers. Are you actually concerned about the system call, or is that just an inherent part of your actual question about invoking programs in different ways?

Comment: I voted as "too broad" because "your question ... has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)," (from https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions in the help center)

Comment: Jeff’s not being rude. After all the time you’ve been using the site, it seems reasonable to expect that you would have understood by now that it works best when a question is a single question, and not a number of more-or-less related questions. Especially in this case since at least some of your questions can be answered from the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer to the question you linked to says

> To begin with, note that `argv[0]` is not necessarily the program name.

which addresses your main question.

Your various questions about starting a program seem to stem from a misunderstanding. You don’t need to use links (symbolic or hard) to start a program with `argv[0]` set to a value other than its name; you need to be able to control the array given to `execve`. This is what `login` does when it starts the shell: it prefixes it with `-` in `argv[0]`.

Bash starts in POSIX mode when its `argv[0]` is `sh`, so that it can be used as `/bin/sh`. If that required using `--posix`, you’d need to change a lot of shell scripts.

The same reasoning applies to using `-` for a login shell: this convention works with any shell, whether it supports a `--login` option or not.

The login use-case is an example of when it’s useful for `argv[0]` to not be equal to the program’s name.