# Why does rbash not apply any restrictions for a login shell on Debian 9 (Stretch)?

Tags: debian, login, restricted-shell

I am on Debian 9 (Stretch). I have a `deploy` user where I've set the shell to `/bin/rbash`. Here is the line from `/etc/passwd`:

```
deploy:x:9000:9000::/home/deploy:/bin/rbash
```

If I am the root user, and I run `su - deploy` or `su -l deploy`, then it starts `rbash` (`echo $SHELL  # => /bin/rbash`), but commands are not being restricted:

```
~$ echo $SHELL  
/bin/rbash
~$ cd /tmp
/tmp$ echo asdf > /tmp/file
/tmp$ /bin/cat /tmp/file  
asdf   
# (Should not allow any commands with a slash)
```

If I just run `su deploy`:

```
~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/rbash
~$ cd /tmp
rbash: cd: restricted
~$ /bin/cat /etc/passwd
rbash: /bin/cat: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names
```

Why doesn't `rbash` apply any restrictions if this is a login shell?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` just lists the login shell, but that doesn't prove that you're running it. What does `echo $0 $-` report?

Comment: Thanks @muru, the output of `echo $0 $-` is: `-su himBHs`

Comment: Ah interesting, if I run `su deploy`, then the output of `echo $-` is `himrBHs`, where the `r` is the `--restricted` flag. I wonder why it's not being added for `su - deploy`?

Answer (score 4):

From the Bash manual:

> If Bash is started with the name `rbash`, or the `--restricted` or `-r` option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted.

Now, "started with the name" means that `$0`, or [the zeroth element of `argv`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315819/70524) is that name. But when `su` starts it as a login shell, it sets the name to `-su`. And the `-r` option wasn't used either, so neither method of starting a restricted shell was used when `su` starts a login shell.

It should still take effect for other, proper means of login (such as SSH, or `login(1)` over a TTY).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I think you might be right!

I've discovered something else in the [su man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/su1.html), in the `--shell` section that talks about the shell that will be invoked. It says that shell will be chosen first from the `-s` or `--shell` flag, then if `--preserve-environment` is used, it uses the existing `$SHELL` variable. Finally it looks at the entry in `/etc/passwd`.

So I've been able to force the restricted bash shell by running: `su -s /bin/rbash deploy`. (And `su -p -s /bin/rbash deploy`, since I want the same env.)

Comment: But for some reason this still doesn't work if I run `su -l -s /bin/rbash deploy`. The bash flags are still `himBHs`, and it's not a restricted shell. If I run `echo $0`, I still get: "-su".

Comment: The other problem is that `su -s /bin/rbash deploy` doesn't load the `deploy` user's `.bashrc` or `.profile`, which is why I wanted the `-l` flag.

Comment: I also tried `exec -a rbash su -l deploy` to change the name in $0, but that didn't seem to do anything. `echo $0` still shows: `-su`. But I finally realized that I can pass an argument to bash by using `--`.

My final command is: `exec su -l -p -s /bin/rbash deploy -- -r`. Now `echo $0` shows returns `-su`, but I'm explicitly passing the `--restricted` flag (`-r`), so `echo $-` shows `hirBHs`. (And I checked that I can't turn it off with `set +r`.)

(exec is also a great idea because an attacker can't just `exit` to get back to the root user.)

Comment: One last thing! This command was still trying to load the `.bashrc` for the root user, because `$HOME` was not being reset properly (even though the `su` man page says that it should be.) So I needed to explicitly set the `$HOME` variable so that it loads the correct `.bashrc`: `export HOME="/home/deploy" && exec su -l -p -s /bin/rbash deploy -- -r`.

Thanks for your help!